# Are python lists row-major ordered or column-major ordered?

Tags: python, performance, list

I read on wikipedia that python is a language that implements **Row-major order**. But I am trying to multiply 2 matrices where I access using a row-major approach and a column-major approach. But when I execute the code, the column-major approach is allways faster.
I'll post here a snippet of my code:

```
class Matrix:

#flag indicates the type of matrix
def __init__(self, num_lines, num_cols, flag):
    self.num_lines = num_lines
    self.num_cols = num_cols
    if flag == 0:
        # First Matrix
        self.matrix = [1]*num_lines*num_cols
    elif flag == 1:
        # Second Matrix
        self.matrix = [0]*num_lines*num_cols
        for i in range(num_lines):
            for j in range(num_cols):
                self.matrix[i*num_cols+j] = i+1
    elif flag == 2:
        # Result Matrix
        self.matrix = self.matrix = [0]*num_lines*num_cols

def setMatrixValue(self, line, column, value):
    self.matrix[line*self.num_cols + column] = value

def getMatrixValue(self, line, column):
    return self.matrix[line*self.num_cols + column]






def multiplyMatrices(num_lines, num_cols, flag):
    matrix_a = Matrix(num_lines, num_cols, 0)
    matrix_b = Matrix(num_cols, num_lines, 1) 
    matrix_result = Matrix(num_lines, num_lines, 2)

    # Column-major approach
    if flag == 0:
        start_time = time.time()
        for i in range(matrix_result.num_lines):
            for j in range(matrix_result.num_cols):
                temp = 0
                for k in range(matrix_a.num_cols):
                    temp += matrix_a.getMatrixValue(i, k) * matrix_b.getMatrixValue(k, j)
                matrix_result.setMatrixValue(i,j,temp)
    # Row-major approach
    elif flag == 1:
         start_time = time.time()
         for i in range(matrix_result.num_lines):
            for k in range(matrix_result.num_cols):
                for j in range(matrix_a.num_lines):
                    matrix_result.setMatrixValue(i,j, matrix_result.getMatrixValue(i,j) + (matrix_a.getMatrixValue(i,k) * matrix_b.getMatrixValue(k,i)))                 

    end_time = time.time()
    print matrix_result.matrix
    diffTime(start_time, end_time)
```

And I just realised that matrices multiplication in python is so much slower than Java or C++. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Lists don't have an order in that manner since they only support a single dimension.

Comment: Python doesn't really have 2-d arrays, so it's not really row-major or column major.  Of course, you can make a list of lists in which case:  `matrix[index]` will pick out a sublist which you can then index again:  `matrix[index][subindex]` -- But the items are unlikely to be in any sort of consistent row-major or column major order in memory.  If you want to do this sort of work in python, you should look into numpy which implements a matrix class (or 2d array class) which will likely suit your needs (with good performance)

Comment: In python this is kind of a null point - all objects are references, and so any array is just a series of pointers to random memory. I'm pretty sure the location of the actual objects is implementation dependent, i.e. not par of the spec, and so not reliable cross platform - i.e. dangerous teritory.

Comment: @mgilson i don't think even items in a 1D array are going to be next to each other in memory are they? You can use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) and the `@jit` decorator on loops to try and improve stuff like this, but i don't think it's in any way defined in the spec, and hence not something you should rely upon in any program you write.

Comment: If you are going to be performing matrix calculations and other numerical work, you should consider using numerical libraries, such as [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). Far better than reinventing the wheel and (much) faster too.

Comment: @will -- Not with a `list`.  Python does have an infrequently used `array` module which (IIRC) is pretty much just a wrapper around C arrays.  Most people who want `array` generally end up downloading numpy though as it is a lot more powerful.

Comment: @mgilson, but you still need to create `int` or `float` instances from the array items to be able to do _anything_ compared with numpy

Comment: @JohnLaRooy-AKAgnibbler -- Not sure I'm getting your point :-).  Numpy has it's own type wrappers (np.int32 e.g.)... When you're working with the number on the python side, you're still working with a python object, not directly a C object, so I don't see how that's much different than what `array` provides (with the exception that you can't build a 2 dimensional array with `array` as I've alread said ... ;-)

Comment: @mgilson, I mean you can do a bunch of intermediate numpy operations on your arrays before converting back to Python objects. Consider the OP code. If `self.matrix` was an array, `getMatrixValue` still has to create all those `int` objects to return, so you lose the advantage of sequential memory accesses

Comment: @JohnLaRooy-AKAgnibbler -- Ahh.  Right.  So in no ways was I trying to promote the usage of `array` for this task.  My point was mainly that there is no row-major/column-major order for python objects and the easiest way to get a contiguous block of memory in vanilla python is to use the `array` module.  Furthermore, as you're advocating (and I agree), `numpy` is better suited for most tasks where you might use `array` if you can bear the external dependency.

Comment: If you profile the two approaches, what does it say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour you are expecting is caused by the advantage of accessing sequential memory addresses. So here

```
self.matrix[line*self.num_cols + column]
```

You would want to be incrementing column in the inner loop.

There are a few problems with this concept in pure Python. Since all the ints are objects - to access them, you are first getting a reference from the list sequentially (good), but then you need to access the memory of the reference (non sequential) to get the int object (bad).

Fortunately there are alternatives, such as numpy. Which additionally has  well tested matrix routines you can use.

Comment: I don't see how this really answers the question, why is the "column major approach" faster?

Comment: @will, it isn't. It is faster in some lower level languages on many modern CPUs due to the way the CPU is implemented.

Comment: I understand that the prefetcher helps when the items and contiguous in memory (and for the more advanced ones row/colum major doesn't matter so much as it can work out the stride) - what i'm saying is that you don't explain why the column major approach is faster in this example.

Comment: Is it just that the lists are contiguous in memory, so that the initial access to the object references are faster? And if so, surely this is only a small effect that is only seen here since memory access is slow compared to the actual operations.

Comment: @will, the problem is that Python will have more random memory accesses than say C while looping over the array - this largely defeats the prefetcher. Additionally - any difference would be difficult to detect since the runtime of Python has to do a lot more work per iteration of the array

Comment: Yah that's what i thought the case was, obviously python is slower than java and C because the memory addresses are not sequential, but that doesn't explain why his column major approach is faster than the row major approach - python implements lists as arrays, so the locations of the references are next to each other, surely this means that when doing the operations one way it will still have the old pointers in the cache, and so there will be fewer cache misses, even though it has to then follow those to a new location each time - it doesn't wipe the whole cache when there's a miss does it?

Answer (score 4):

Python is slow because it checks the types of all objects at runtime to decide what operations to perform (e.g. which **mult** should it use when it sees '*').  Not only that but most abstractions on simple data types have a runtime cost as you marshall data in and out of the object.

You can mitigate some of these speed problems by using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). e.g.

```
import numpy
numpy.matrix([0, 1]) * numpy.matrix([[0], [1]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think that using numpy will make that each matrix position will be next to each inside memory? Can I rely on this method to compare with other languages?

Comment: @sheepCow -- You can't guarantee that numpy will keep items next to each other in memory.  There are a lot of cases where that isn't true (e.g. slices which return views).  However, eventually under all the layers of numpy wrapping, the underlying data is contiguous (and that can be relied on) and stored in row-major order -- But to the user, that is more or less opaque.  You can create a column-major array (for all intents and purposes)  simply by taking the transpose of a row-major array (the underlying data will *often* be the same)

Comment: @mgilson Is it fair to say that `numpy` is row major? From what i recall the vast majority of numpy routines have a kwarg `order` that allows you to specify if it's row or column major (though they use the labels `C` and `Fortran` orders) - [numpy.array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

Comment: @will -- I think that's probably fair.  I'm not a numpy dev (so I could be wrong on this point), but my guess is that the data is always stored in row-major order and that the `order` flag just tells numpy how to iterate over the data underneath everything.

Comment: Do you think? I would guess the opposite: the only reason to provide that kind of option would be performance which depended on the row/column layout. Since the memory location is abstracted completely away from you in the python (ignoring in-lining C), it can't have any effect anywhere other than in the numpy side - why else would it be an option?

Comment: @will -- I don't have time to look into it just now, but [this reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html) might be illuminating.